# Viewing rails test from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running a test that I've created in rails using a simple assert_select that should populate 5 divs based on my fixtures. But every time it's failing saying 0 elements were found, when 5 were expected. Is it possible to see the output that the test is basing this on?

Below is the specific test that's giving me trouble:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select '.contentBox', minimum: 5
  end
end
```

and the error:

> ```
> Finished tests in 0.403847s, 2.4762 tests/s, 4.9524 assertions/s.
>
>   1) Failure:
> test_should_get_index(PostsControllerTest) [/var/www/site/test/functional/posts_controller_test.rb:7]:
> Expected at least 5 elements matching ".contentBox", found 0.
>
> 1 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
> rake aborted!
> ```

It should be noted that when manually adding everything from rails console (e.g. Post.new, etc) everything works fine and I can manually check the source and see that there are the appropriate number of  items. So it leads me to believe that I've done something wrong with the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `puts @response.body` to print the body of the page that is returned if you want to inspect it. You could also consider using Capybara which if you did you could use `put page.body`

What you will have to add to the test is creating 5 posts. So doing something like:

```
class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    puts @response.body #This should print what is returned from get:index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select '.contentBox', minimum: 5
  end
end
```

Update for question in comments:
  If you have in your controller:
  `@posts = Post.all`

Then in your view you should have something like:

```
<% @post.all do |post| %>
  <div class="contentBox">
    Title: <%= post.title %> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Should `puts @response.body` be placed in the test? I don't seem to get any output if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, it should be in the test and should be after the request is made to the controller so the response is available. This may help as well http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#instance-variables-available. Also, if it is not too revealing, seeing the test may help.

Comment: I've updated the post to include the test and error that I'm getting.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam. Placing puts @response.body before the assert worked. One last quick question more directly related to my issue. Is there a way for the fixtures that I've set up to automatically do what you've done in 5.times do?

Comment: You actually are correct, I forgot you had said you were using fixtures sorry! Just to test that they are being loaded correctly though, if you place `puts Post.all` in place of the `5.times do` block what is the result? You should see the 5 posts from the fixtures, if not something may be wrong with how the fixtures are being loaded.

Comment: The result is: `#<Post:0x0000000286a590>
#<Post:0x000000028cdc30>
#<Post:0x000000028cd618>
#<Post:0x000000028cd000>
#<Post:0x000000028d49b8>`, so does that mean that something must be wrong with the controller in that it's not pushing the content into the view?

Comment: Either that, or the view is not actually displaying the posts correctly. I will update my answer with some more detail for formattings sake. Good news is the fixtures look to be working so I will remove the 5.times block from my answer.

Comment: Thank you :) I think I've milked this question quite a bit. I opened up another one more specific to my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767361/rails-fixtures-not-appearing-in-test

Comment: For anyone that may come back, my specific issue stemmed from a controller where method that was using => false instead of => 0 (which seems to be the only way sqlite3 will interpret a false entry).